# Convert discus output into readable HTML mail

Tags: bash, shell-script, escape-characters, ascii

How can I take the DISCUS command output below:

[image: Screenshot of colored discus output]

and convert it into something HTML email friendly? I've bash scripted something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
discus > /tmp/discus.log
touch /tmp/diskchart.log
    echo "To: myaddy@domain.com" > /tmp/diskchart.log
    echo "Subject: Weekly Disk Report" >> /tmp/diskchart.log
    echo "MIME-Version: 1.0" >> /tmp/diskchart.log
    echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"us-ascii\"" >> /tmp/diskchart.log
    echo "Content-Disposition: inline" >> /tmp/diskchart.log
    echo "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">" >> /tmp/diskchart.log
    echo "<html>" >> /tmp/diskchart.log
    echo "<div>" >> /tmp/diskchart.log
    cat /tmp/discus.log | grep / | grep -v run | /usr/bin/awk '{print $1}{print $9}' >> /tmp/diskchart.log
    echo "</div>" >> /tmp/diskchart.log
    echo "</html>" >> /tmp/diskchart.log
    mail -s "SAT Weekly Disk Report" myaddy@domain.com < /tmp/diskchart.log
#rm  /tmp/discus.log /tmp/diskchart.log
```

but that produces an output which looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of output with escape characters]

Anyone know how to deal with the escape characters showing up in the actual mail? I'd ideally like to see the bar graph as shown above. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Comment: are you sure you want text/html?  text/plain would be adequate (and better) for a simple email like this.  also, you don't need the two grep statements, awk can do regexp matching.  try `discus -c  | awk '/\// && !/\/run/ {print $1,$9}'`

Comment: Thanks for that pointer Craig.  Very much appreciated :)

Comment: Combined with Stephane's reply, I actually ended up using "pydf" instead of "Discus" for the relevant mounts.  Worked out brilliantly !

Answer (score 2):

You could use [aha](https://github.com/theZiz/aha) (also packaged in some Linux distributions), to convert the ANSI colouring sequences to HTML:

```
#! /bin/sh -
sendmail -t -oi << EOF
To: myaddy@domain.com
Subject: Weekly Disk Report
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Disposition: inline

$(discus | aha)
EOF
```

Comment: good answer, a herenow document is a much better (certainly more readable) way than lots of echo statements.  The discus output needs to be surrounded by <pre> and </pre> tags, otherwise the columns wont line up properly when displayed...or send the mail as text/plain.  or, as Faisal wanted only fields 1 and 9, use `discus -c  | awk '/\// && !/\/run/ {print $1,$9}'`

Comment: @CraigSanders, my version of `aha` at least does include the `<pre>`, `</pre>` tags.

Comment: Thank you @ Stephane Chazelas & Craig Sanders.  This really gets me headed in the right direction.  Much obliged!

PS - Thanks to moderator for adding images inline :)